# Multipart urls in flask with url_for()

Tags: python, web, flask

How can I use url_for() to access a route defined like `@app.route('/user/add')`? I've tried `url_for('user/add')` but to no avail.

I get error `'BuildError: ('projects/add', {}, None)'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not use the URL path with `url_for`. Instead, each route you give is assigned an "endpoint", which is what you use in `url_for`. For example...

```
@app.route('/user/add', endpoint='useradd')
def add_user():
   pass
```

If you do this, you explicitly say what the "endpoint" is. Then, you can use...

```
url_for('useradd')
```

However, if you don't explicitly add the "endpoint", one is automatically determined from the name of the function. So, if you did...

```
@app.route('/user/add')
def add_user():
   pass
```

...then the endpoint would be "add_user", because that is the name of the function...

```
url_for('add_user')
```

Answer (score 2):

you should pass the function name of the route as an argument of url_for()
for example:

```
@app.route('/user/add')
def add():
    pass
```

using url_for should be like this:

```
url_for("add")
```